# 3D open source physics engine suitable for mobile platforms (Android and iOS)

Tags: open-source, mobile, physics-engine

I have made some research and found that bullet, ode, newton and some others are open source physics engines that should be portable enough (but I have never tried to comile/use anyone of them on phones). I am writing my games for mobile platforms in C++, so the engine should be C or C++. I need a fast engine, since mobile platforms have limited resources. I need a free engine. A good design would be nice to have too.

What engine is best suited for my task?
What I really would like to hear from you is your direct experience.

Documentation and support (for example, forum or an IRC channel) is a really important aspect to take into consideration.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation... Looking forward to a good answer.

Comment: As a mater of fact I started with bullet after looking around for quite some time. Since I started browsing in 2009 I saw bullet evolve and gain more support. It was used by some of my coworkers and it works... So ATM I started integrating bullet tentatively into my mobile engine.

Comment: Voting to close as "which technology should I use?" questions are now off topic according to the FAQ.

Answer (score 4):

[Bullet Physics](http://bulletphysics.org/wordpress/) is the choice I'd go with if you absolutely require opensource. It's pretty much THE choice in your situation. If not, physx and havoc both have non-commercial licenses.

Here is a more complete list
http://www.gamedev.net/topic/475753-list-of-physics-engines-and-reference-material-updated-7-march-2011/

Comment: +1 for Bullet. It's well docummented, and has plenty of tutorials and examples on the web. Don't know about the support part though.

Comment: Bullet's primary developer is an employee of Sony. I don't think commercial support is available for Bullet, but the Bullet Physics forums are always helpful.