# How to implement a physical with perspective effect on Android?

Tags: opengl, android, physics, physics-engine

I'm working on a project that looks like [PaperToss](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bfs.papertoss). Instead of tossing a page, you toss a coin. Suppose that I have a coin put in three-dimensional that have coordinates at A(x,y,z). I throw that point ahead, after 1/100 second, that coin move from A(x,y,z) to A'(x',y',z'). By this way, I  have two problems need to solve.

1. Where will be the coin at time t?
2. How can I display this on a screen?

For 2., I thought about using [Orthographic projection & Perspective projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection). I'm told that OpenGL can help me, but I don't know how.

How can I solve 1. and 2.?

Answer (score 1):

1. You are probably looking for [motion equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion). However, I would advice you to use a [3D physics engine](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20580/3d-open-source-physics-engine-suitable-for-mobile-platforms-android-and-ios).
2. Well, if you want to draw a 3D world in a 2D canvas (aka, the device's screen), then the way to go is OpenGL, that aims exactly that.